# Google App Scipt Utilites.unzip does not work with zip files from outside script

Tags: google-apps-script, unzip

My Google App script that unzip attachments of a Gmail message does not work with
zip files from outside script.

When I use Utilities.unzip method, like this

```
var unzippedBlob =Utilities.unzip(zippedBlob);
```

I always end up with an error '*We're sorry, a server error occurred. Please wait a bit and try again*.' since then.

Does anyone see the same error?

Comment: You've verified this occurs with zipped data created by the same script? If so then you need to file a bug report, not ask us how to make it work - this isn't Google Support :)

Comment: @tehhowch It works with zip files created by Google Apps Script but zip files came from other apps like 7-zip or Win standard archiver. Could you let me know how it works with any zip files?

Comment: You can try to open a bug on their public issue tracker [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new).

Comment: I found that double byte characters (Japanese) filename in zip files cause this error.